# Only Displaying a subset of items in Datagrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So this is not really a question but a solution to the problem I have had for the past 3 days, any improvement is welcomed. So I have a datagrid that displays selected product, each product can also have child items called ingredients, these ingredients should be added to the collection but not displayed to the user.

The solution I came up for this is the below. The commented out where clause was my first attempt.

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductSaleTransaction> gProductSale = new ObservableCollection<ProductSaleTransaction>();        
        public ObservableCollection<ProductSaleTransaction> ProductSaleCollection
        {
            get { return gProductSale/*.Where(s => s.category != "Ingredients").ToObservableCollection<ProductSaleTransaction>()*/; }
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {    
                    dgProductTchSale.ItemsSource = ProductSaleCollection;
                    ProductSaleCollection.CollectionChanged += ProductSaleCollection_CollectionChanged;
        }
        private void ProductSaleCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                 ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ProductSaleCollection);
                    view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(filterIngredient);
        }
public bool filterIngredient(object item)
{
        var vaitem = (ProductSaleTransaction)item;
        if (vaitem == null)
            return false;
        else
        {
            bool it = false;
            it = vaitem.category != "Ingredient";
            return it;          
        }                        
}
```

This results in all items added to the collection but only items not in the Ingredient category being displayed to the user.

This is what I came up with to solve automatic filtering of items I want to save to database with all downstream code but not to display them to the user.

Comment: People are encouraged to answer their own questions, but it should follow our Question and Answer format. That allows others to search for problems and to post alternative answers. Post code that demonstrates the problem in the Question field, and post your answer below in the Answer field. After a day or so you can choose your own answer.

Comment: Thanks @DourHighArch will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter of `ICollectionView` is evaluated automatically when its underlying collection adds/removes items. So, you don't need to create a new `ICollectionView` everytime the collection changes.

Instead move the lines

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ProductSaleCollection);
view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(filterIngredient);
```

to `Window_Loaded` itself and remove `ProductSaleCollection_CollectionChanged` event.